# Solution for high frequency of Deleting and Inserting records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, mongodb, insert

My program (a game server) frequently delete many records from a table and then Insert many Records into a table as well. 
The use-case is:

1. A character may have many items, and each item has its properties.
2. Once a character is loaded into the game, his items stored in memory.
3. When the character exists the game, all the old records (before character is loaded to the game) will be deleted and the program will insert the character's new items back to database.
4. A character has average of 100 items (100 records of items and 100 others for item properties)

When CCU reach about 1k, mysql will become very slow controling those reads/writes.

I try many ways to optimize MySQL, but they are just not good enough. My temporary workaround is using a SSD disk for MySQL data folder.

My question is: should I use other DBMS (currently considering MongoDB ...) and what should I pick?

Comment: Are you saying it loads all records, and then deletes everything, and rewrites it (and that there are 1000 users concurrently attempting this same operation)? Has every record changed every time this happens?

Comment: It's my assumption, however, it happens when I wanna disconnect all users from the server ... Engine = MyISAM

Comment: Rule of thumb: only update data that's changed.  Mass update mass insert for sake of simplicity of code is generally not the right course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can handle a lot of things, but tables with frequent `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` options will cause severe degradation. It's possible to keep MySQL running under heavy loads, but for situations like this you'll want to shard into different tables or databases.

Using SSD for MySQL is not a bad idea at all, though.

If you can architect your system around a fast key-value store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) you might have all the performance you could ever want provided all that data can fit in memory.

Comment: Personally, I think Redis is not good for this case, because the involvement of many properties for an item, and sometime I have to search through those items (such as searching for Item with same ItemID) ... 
Shard into different tables or db is also not a good solution (what I think) because the problem here is that we have a lot of disk access in a short period of time ... different tables, databases but same disk huh?

Comment: What's to prevent you from sharding across different volumes? Redis can be tricky to work with if you try and use it like a relational database, but if you plan out things carefully in advance you can create exactly the index structures you need and use those to do the searching.

Comment: I'm not gonna use a lot of volumes, a SSD is indeed better than that option. However, to think abt Redis now, I got your point, maybe I will mix  up mysql and Redis... Thanks for your suggestion